# Creating a Postulate Environment

Tags: environments, theorems

I understand how to use the theorem environment in LaTex and would like to know if there is a similar environment for postulates or how I can make an environment for postulates on my own.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\newtheorem{post}{Postulate}
```

or

```
\newtheorem{post}{Postulate}[chapter] (or [section])
```

in the preamble should be enough. Now you can use packages, such as `amsthm` or `ntheorem` to customise the layout of this new environment.

Comment: Thanks that works! Is there any way to get rid of the period after the number so that it just says **Postulate 1** not **Postulate 1.**?

Comment: It depends on the package you use. I don't know very well `amsthm`, but with `ntheorem`, you must add  `theoremseparator{}` if you don't want the full stop, or, say `theoremseparator{ — }` if you want an emdash (old style typography!) *before* declaring the environment.